# Find same name in a table in different PDF files

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

i need to find if in different pdf files there is a given name that is present in 2 or more files. the table in the files that i use is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCXsj.jpg)

and i want to excract and compare only the strings under the "name surname" column and if they are the same, print them.

```
nomi_comuni = []

for file_path in ['documento1.pdf', 'documento2.pdf']:
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
        from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
        from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
        from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
        from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
        from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
        from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
        from pdfminer.layout import LTTextBox, LTTextLine
        from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator

        parser = PDFParser(file)

        document = PDFDocument(parser)

        rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()

        laparams = LAParams()

        device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)

        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

        for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):

            interpreter.process_page(page)

            layout = device.get_result()

            for element in layout:

                if isinstance(element, LTTextBox) or isinstance(element, LTTextLine):

                    parole = element.get_text().split()

                for indice, parola in enumerate(parole):

                    if parola == 'name':

                        if indice < len(parole) - 1:

                            nomi_comuni.append(parole[indice + 1])


print(nomi_comuni)
```

i wrote this code, it runs, but it doesn't give me what i want

Comment: Please be more specific as to your issues with this code.

Comment: my issues with this code is that if i have two pdf files with tables which has the same name and surname (i.e. "jane doe"), this code doesn't print that name but "surname, surname, surname" etc (based on the number of files i give to it) because when it found the word "name", since it present in the pdf files i pass to it, it print the word immediately after it which is "surname", not the name of the person

Comment: the point is that i don't know what names there are in the files, this is why i need a program to do that. i have X files with Y names in them and i want to extract the name that are present in 2 or more files. but of course i don't know what are the name otherwise i wouldn't need to write a program

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I already clarified my problem and i gave all the informations i have